# Lenient CSV parsing

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Most java based CSV parsing implementations seem to discard the remainder of the stream in case of csv format errors. Examples are OpenCSV (which silently terminates processing) and [CSVeed](http://csveed.org/) (which terminates noisily with a line and column number).

Any recommendations for a parser/configuration that will skip over faulty lines, warn and continue processing the remaining valid lines would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com/). You can set data policy attribute on [UniversalDataReader](http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/topic/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/datareader.html), that defines, what to do with invalid values/records.